# Filtrado en dataframe en python

Tags: python, pandas

Quería saber cómo llevar a cabo un proceso en el que me he atascado.
Tengo un dataframe con una columna llamada Pedidos la cual solo tiene datos que o empiezan por P o empiezan por A. También tengo otra columna llamada 'P&L'en la que hay valores negativos y positivos.

Quería crear una columna nueva en la que ponga Analizar en los siguientes casos:
1- Cuando el dato de la columna 'Pedido' empiece por P y su valor en la columna P&L' sea menor que cero.
2- Cuando los datos de la columna 'Pedido' empiecen por A y su valor en la columna P&L' sea mayor que cero.

Gracias!

Comment: Deberías pasarte por [ask] y realizar el [tour]. Si es posible añade un [mcve] o muestra que has intentando hasta el momento.